# Enable session affinity for canary release with nginx ingress controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, canary-deployment

I'm trying to setup canary-release with Nginx ingress controller. The problem is that it doesn't keep session affinity causing every request to be served by a random service.

My canary ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: canary
  name: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-weight: "50"
```

My default ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
```

Is it currently possible to enable session affinity for canary release with Nginx ingress?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are not the only who have this problem. There is an open issue on github with mostly the same problem: [Session affinity doesn't work for canaries](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3717)

Waiting for fix